# angular $cookieStore not working under controller $scope functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, angular-cookies

I am facing problem while using angular-js with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Everything Working fine with routing, expect $cookieStore not working under the functions defined in controller $scope, may be because of the .HTACCESS i added.

i can't find any solution,now using "window.localStorage" anybody here have a solution

my sample code is follow:

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='doLogin()'>Sign in</button>
```

**APPLICATION SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']);

 app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider 
    .when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardApp'
    })  
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/',
    templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
    controller: 'loginApp'
    });  
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); 
})


app.controller('loginApp', function($scope , $cookieStore ) {

    //This working fine
    $cookieStore.put('Greet','Welcome to Angular!');

    ///////////////////////////////////
    $scope.doLogin = function()
    { 
           // Here no cookie has been setting up
           $cookieStore.put('loggedin', true);
    };
```

})

**.HTACCESS**

```
#BEGIN
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>

#END
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue now. Your post pointed me to the right problem.
I created a plnkr to try to repro and noticed I was able to do $cookieStore.put() just fine inside the $scope method.
So the issue seems to be with verisoning for source files. I was using 1.3.11 for angular.js and angular-cookies.js but 1.3.5 for angular-route.js.

The fix was to use 1.3.11 for angular-route.js or corresponding version that you are using.